# Not able to debug webservice code in IntelliJ

Tags: java, debugging, windows-services, intellij-idea

I have a window service that I have installed.I have the source code of the application opened in Intelli J.

I made configuration IntelliJ as following
[image]

I checked the PID of the service and port it is using.

While running Remote config in Intelli J it is giving following error

```
4:09:18 PM Error running Remote: Unable to open debugger port : java.net.ConnectException "Connection refused: connect"
```

Can someone please shed some light on how to debug window service in IntelliJ. It is a job schedule application.

The installService.cmd is as follows

```
set HOME_DIR=%~dp0
set SERVICE="Service_Name"
SET JAVA_OPTIONS=-Xms256m -Xmx256m
@echo Service name is Service_Name
"pathname\Service_Name.exe" -install %SERVICE% %JVM% %JAVA_OPTIONS% -Djava.class.path="pathname\Service_Name.jar" -Dorg.quartz.properties="pathname/Service_NameScheduler.properties" -start com.org.st.Service_Name -stop com.org.st.Service_Name -out "D:/core_log\Service_Name_service_out.log" -err "D:/core_log\Service_Name_service_error.log" -current "pathname\apps"
set JVM="C:/Program Files/Java/jdk1.6.0_29/jre/bin/server/jvm.dll"
```

Comment: Is the remote windows service open for debug? I mean, does it have the whole command line arguments part defined that you copy from configuration?

Comment: @Vic - I am running the window service on the same computer at which I am running IntelliJ Idea.I am not sure how to look for command line argument for a window service.

Comment: How did you install the service? Is it configured using tanuki wrapper? If this is a java service, there got to be jre arguments somewhere

Comment: @Vic It is installed using Java Service and used custom made installservice.cmd.I have edited my question to include installservice.cmd.

Comment: @C4CodeE4Exe I am getting the same error. Does anyone have a fix?

Comment: @C4CodeE4Exe Does your telnet to the port work?

Comment: @abcd it is not working..let me know if it works

Answer (score 3):

Check the port number. It should be same as in JAVA_OPTIONS & Intellij Idea Debugger remote configuration under port no.

Answer (score 2):

Please append the command line arguments from the IntelliJ debug configuration to the `SET JAVA_OPTIONS` line, it will be something like

```
SET JAVA_OPTIONS=-Xms256m -Xmx256m -Xdebug -Xrunjdwp:transport=dt_socket,server=y,suspend=n,address=51211
```

And reinstall the service.

Comment: I have done it.But upon running Remote config in Debug mode , I am getting "java.net.ConnectException "Connection refused: connect" error.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure whatever port you're listening on isn't blocked by a firewall.